# Function to retrieve a picture if there is no picture is attached

Tags: custom-field

How can i retrieve a picture, let say ( No picture ) when i don't add a picture in my custom field

I use this code to retrive the field...

```
<img class="film" 
     src="/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php the_field('img_actor'); ?>&h=251&w=175&zc=1"
     alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"  
     title="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
```

How to retrive no-picture from this code

```
<?php 
if(get_field('distributie') != ""){$counter=0;foreach(get_field('distributie') as $post_object): ?>
    <div class="act-box">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>" title="Actor <?php echo get_the_title($post_object->ID) ?>">
<img class="actor_img" src="/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo get_field( 'img_actor', $post_object->ID ); ?>&h=70&w=50&zc=1" alt="<?php echo get_the_title($post_object->ID) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_object->ID) ?>" /></a>
        <span class="act-titlu">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>" title="Actor <?php echo get_the_title($post_object->ID) ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_object->ID) ?></a>
        </span>
     </div>
<?php $counter++;if($counter>=8) break; endforeach;}?>
```

If i change

```
<?php echo get_field( 'img_actor', $post_object->ID ); ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo urlencode($img); ?>
```

I get an error ($post_object->ID) where do i put it?

Comment: `the_field` is not a WordPress function, but I'll assume you can check if it's empty or not using a conditional.

Comment: i know how to retrive a picture, the question si how to get a default picture, if no picture is added..

Comment: And where does this default picture come from?

Comment: The picture is in my www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/default.jpg , i added trought FTP ... if there is no picture i want to automate get the default picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the value before you use it:

```
<?php
if ( ! $img = get_field('img_actor', get_the_ID() ) )
    $img = 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/default.jpg';
?>
<img class="film" 
     src="/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo urlencode($img); ?>&h=251&w=175&zc=1"
     alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"  
     title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"/>
```

I recommend **not** to use the same text for `title` and `alt`, this is very annoying for screen reader users.

Comment: Toscho, please look at the first post...

Comment: @LucicaCopil Use `get_the_ID()` to get the post ID.

Comment: if i use that i get all the post owerite with the default picture...

Comment: $img = get_field('img_actor', $post_object->ID  - solve the problem... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use for image redundancy.

1.First it tries to get the featured image
2.Then the first image attached to the post
3.Then a default image.

```
 $attachments = get_children(
                             array(
                                   'numberposts' => 1,
                                   'order'=> 'ASC',
                                   'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                                   'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
                                   'post_status' => null,
                                   'post_type' => 'attachment'
                                   ));

        //first check for featured image
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');

        //no featured image get first attachment   
        } elseif ($attachments) { 

        $first_attachment = reset($attachments);
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($first_attachment->ID, 'thumbnail');

        } else {
            echo '<img src="../something/default.jpg"'; 
        }
```

ps. You can insert the crap timthumb into it if you want or a 4th check for your custom `get_field('img_actor')`